# Converting h5 to another format

Tags: java, hdf5

I've got an h5 file that I'd like to convert to another format.  I know there is the h5dump tool that I can use on Linux but I'd really like to do this from Java without making external calls. I've had a look at their API and ran a few examples but it seems that the examples I've come across don't compile as expected. Does anyone know of a way to convert an h5 file to another format like csv or json from Java without making external calls?

Thanks

Comment: CSV and JSON are kind of meta-file formats in the sense that they are not defined to hold HDF5 data (or any other specific data for that matter). So you may want to specify a specific format you are after. Otherwise you just need something to read the file and convert the elements yourself I suppose.

Comment: Basically I want to use the data elsewhere, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.  So I really just want to extract the data so I can dump it into an RDBMS

Comment: Eh, wouldn't it make more sense to dump it directly from Java? Note that I've never heard about HDF5 up to now. So just a thought.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do.  Dump the h5 file (from Java) into some other format/db

Comment: Well, then you do not need csv and the like. Select from your h5 db using Java and insert each row into whatever other db.